# I have made a mistake, but I can't seem to find what it is. I have tried researching on many platforms. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am an 8th grader that likes coding. I wanted to try out this code, but it is not working. What is wrong with it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to find out the truth.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("Coding is fun! ");
    document.body.appendChild(t);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The posted code works as expected. Therefore the code you are using is different. Are there any errors in the console? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: not yet, but that sounds like something I should do. I have copy and pasted the code in the question straight from my script.

Comment: It works now! Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected. It adds the text when clicking the button.

Have you blocked javascript? Maybe try an other browser.

Comment: I am in fact using About:blank Unfortunately, it keeps on saying Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (<anonymous>:2:1)(function(event){myFunction()
})